# Any way to tell if NFC connection is with a tag or device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc

How can I tell (WP8 C#) if what the device is connected to is a writeable tag or another phone?   The problem is I need to know when to use  `WindowsMime.text/plain` and when to use `WindowsMime:WriteTag.text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`SubscribeForMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.subscribeformessage) method of `ProximityDevice` class in order to subscribe specific types of messages. That way you can know if the nearby device is a writable tag, using, for example, the following code:

```cs
ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();    
device.SubscribeForMessage("WriteableTag", WriteableTagDetected);
```

Then you can do what you want when a tag is detected:

```cs
private void WriteableTagDetected(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{
    // Do something here.
}
```